# Give Area51 GIS more time please

Tags: discussion

I've posted [worried about Area51 project (GIS) getting closed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68079/worried-about-area51-project-gis-getting-closed), a plea to give us more time to grow this community. Lend your voice to the discussion. Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Joel Spolsky assured us, in the linked thread, that *"...GIS will probably stay in beta longer than average to make sure it builds up a solid user base before passing out of beta, but as long as the content on the site is high quality and people can get answers to their questions, you shouldn't worry about the site actually being closed. In the meantime you should be voting a lot to help build up the number of users on that site with moderation privileges. "*